# Hibernate merge with flush not updating data

Tags: java, hibernate, merge

I've finding a solution but nothing works for me, here's the code:

Update function:

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

...

public void updatePositionProfile(PositionProfile positionProfile) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.merge(positionProfile);
    session.flush();
}
```

Entity (getters and setter ommited):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "position_profile")
public class PositionProfile implements Serializable {

    @Embeddable
    public static class PositionProfile_PK implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @NotNull
        @Column(name="id_position")
        Integer id_position;

        @NotNull
        @Column(name="profile")
        String profile;

        @NotNull
        @Column(name="line")
        String line;

        PositionProfile_PK(){
            this.id_position = 0;
            this.profile = new String();
            this.line = "";
        }
    }

    @Id
    PositionProfile_PK positionProfilePK;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="MAX_SPEED")
    private Integer max_speed;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="WARNING_SPEED")
    private Integer warning_speed;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="EMERGENCY_SPEED")
    private Integer emergency_speed;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="DISABLED")
    private String disabled;

    PositionProfile(){
        super();
        this.positionProfilePK = new PositionProfile_PK();
        this.max_speed = 0;
        this.warning_speed = 0;
        this.emergency_speed = 0;
        this.disabled = " ";
    }
}
```

Controller (summarized for brevity):

```
PositionProfile positionProfileToUpdate = positionProfile.getPositionProfileByIdPositionAndProfile(pk, profile);
positionProfileToUpdate.setMax_speed(ms);
positionProfile.updatePositionProfile(positionProfileToUpdate);
```

I've tryed with update() function and saveOrUpdate() but it doesn't work, I don't know what's happening. Session is never closed so the entity is attached. I've checked that values are changed correctly in the object I passed to updatePositionProfile() function, but when merge() it simply does nothing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you make flush, the PositionProfile is only for the same session visible.

You must check, if the `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();` working correctly